# Aggregating unbalanced panel to time series using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an unbalanced panel that I'm trying to aggregate up to a regular, weekly time series. The panel looks as follows:

```
Group     Date        value
 A       1/1/2000       5
 A       1/17/2000      10
 B       1/9/2000       3
 B       1/23/2000      7
 C       1/22/2000      20
```

To give a better sense of what I'm looking for, I'm including an intermediate step, which I'd love to skip if possible. Basically some data needs to be filled in so that it can be aggregated. As you can see, missing weeks in between observations are interpolated. All other values are set equal to zero.

```
Group    Date        value
  A     1/1/2000      5
  A     1/8/2000      5
  A     1/15/2000     10
  A     1/22/2000     0
  B     1/1/2000      0
  B     1/8/2000      3
  B     1/15/2000     3
  B     1/22/2000     7
  C     1/1/2000      0
  C     1/8/2000      0
  C     1/15/2000     0
  C     1/22/2000     20
```

The final result that I'm looking for is as follows:

```
 Date      value           
1/1/2000     5 = 5 + 0 + 0          
1/8/2000     8 = 5 + 3 + 0           
1/15/2000    13 = 10 + 3 + 0           
1/22/2000    27 = 0 + 7 + 20
```

I haven't gotten very far, managed to create a panel:

```
panel = df.set_index(['Group','week']).to_panel()
```

Unfortunately, if I try to resample, I get an error

```
panel.resample('W')
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you ask for a process to interpolate, or a process to aggregate, or both? Also, can you provide a snippet of what you have tried?

Comment: I updated the post. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Very nice and clear update. Is day 1 always starting on Sunday?

Comment: Doesn't matter what day it starts on. It can be Sunday if that's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the key is to resample a groupby object like so:

```
df_temp = (df.set_index('date')
           .groupby('Group')
           .resample('W', how='sum', fill_method='ffill'))

ts = (df_temp.reset_index()
      .groupby('date')
      .sum()[value])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume `df` is your second dataframe with weeks, you can try the following:

```
df.groupby('week').sum()['value']
```

The documentation of `groupby()` and its application is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). It's similar to group-by function in SQL.

---

To obtain the second dataframe from the first one, try the following:

Firstly, prepare a function to map the day to week

```
def d2w_map(day):
    if day <=7:
        return 1
    elif day <= 14:
        return 2
    elif day <= 21:
        return 3
    else:
        return 4
```

In the method above, days from 29 to 31 are considered in week 4. But you get the idea. You can modify it as needed.

Secondly, take the lists out from the first dataframe, and convert days to weeks

```
df['Week'] = df['Day'].apply(d2w_map)
del df['Day']
```

Thirdly, initialize your second dataframe with only columns of 'Group' and 'Week', leaving the 'value' out. Assume now your initialized new dataframe is `result`, you can now do a join

```
result = result.join(df, on=['Group', 'Week'])
```

Last, write a function to fill the `Nan` up in the 'value' column with the nearby element. The `Nan` is what you need to interpolate. Since I am not sure how you want the interpolation to work, I will leave it to you.

---

Here is how you can change d2w_map to convert string of date to integer of week

```
from datetime import datetime
def d2w_map(day_str):
    return datetime.strptime(day_str, '%m/%d/%Y').weekday()
```

Returned value of 0 means Monday, 1 means Tuesday and so on.

If you have the package `dateutil` installed, the function can be more robust:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
def d2w_map(day_str):
    return parse(day_str).weekday()
```

Sometimes, things you want are already implemented by magic :)

Comment: Thanks, but the bulk of my issue is getting to the second dataframe.

Comment: thanks. I used day and week for simplicity. In the actual dataset, day is some date in a five year period. For weeks, I was hoping for a weekly period, not an integer. Sorry for the confusion, will update the question.

Comment: @Luke Hmm..so day 1 doesn't start on Sunday. The only thing that need to changed here is d2w_map function. If your date is string, parse it into datetime object using dateuntils.parser.parse. You should be able to get the weekly information from there, depending on what you want

Comment: Changing d2w_map won't work, unless I create if statements for each week interval over a four year period...

Comment: @Luke date object has a function called weekday()

Comment: @Luke updated how you would convert strings to days in week as an example

Answer (score 0):

Used this tab delimited test.txt:

```
    Group   Date    value
    A   1/1/2000    5
    A   1/17/2000   10
    B   1/9/2000    3
    B   1/23/2000   7
    C   1/22/2000   20
```

You can skip the intermediate datafile as follows. Don't have time now. Just play around with it to get it right.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    time_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
    Y = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep="\t")
    dates = Y['Date']
    dates_right_format = map(lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, time_format), dates)
    values = Y['value']
    X = pd.DataFrame(values)
    X.index = dates_right_format
    print X
    X = X.sort()
    print X
    print X.resample('W', how=sum, closed='right', label='right')
```

Last print

```
                value
    2000-01-02      5
    2000-01-09      3
    2000-01-16    NaN
    2000-01-23     37
```